# d3jsv4 world chart - highlighting specific countries on a map that share similar date/time properties

Tags: d3.js

I am exploring the idea of using a world map -- to highlight specific countries, color coded in a group per say that have a similar startdate date/time.

[image]

my latest js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/aLh9d51t/1/

based on these two examples
http://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f
https://bl.ocks.org/piwodlaiwo/73f7a0e28c53d26c04f30a754de49085

I don't want a tooltip at this stage -- and I am unsure do I have to make a specific call to get world map data polygon information? https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1/world/110m.json  - is this part of the d3v4 lib?  https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js ?

for now - I want to highlight just the 2 countries in this dummy json

```
var population = [
  {
    "id": "CHN",
    "name": "China",
    "population": "1330141295"
  }, {
    "id": "IND",
    "name": "India",
    "population": "1173108018"
  }
];
```

but then group countries based on a startTime

```
var population = [
  {
    "id": "CHN",
    "name": "China",
    "startTime" : Date.parse('2020-01-14T15:00:00Z'),
    "population": "1330141295"
  }, {
    "id": "IND",
    "name": "India",
    "startTime" : Date.parse('2020-01-14T15:00:00Z'),
    "population": "1173108018"
  }, {
    "id": "ECU",
    "name": "Ecuador",
    "startTime" : Date.parse('2020-01-14T16:00:00Z'),
    "population": "14790608"
  }
];
```

so in this example -- India and China will be red because they start on the same day and time 15:00, but Ecuador will be blue because it starts on a 16:00 group.

Comment: I found some world map stuff here - http://jsfiddle.net/duck0/p4uxuhvv/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7qo4u1ag/  - using less libs